# Intelij php autocomplete not working for custom class

Tags: php, intellij-idea, autocomplete

I develop Android, but now I lean PHP. Because I know Intelij I'd like to develope PHP in Intelij.
My problem is autocomplete for  custom classes doesn't work.
I mean e.g. I have a class called customer, and if I'd like to include it, it offers automatically to include customers.php when I write the first few letters of the class name.
But after if I'd like to write

```
$customer = new customer($name);
```

even I press ctrl+spance Intelij doesn't offers any suggestions and ctrl+p at params doesn't works either.
Anyway for other classes both of them are works. I searched for plugins and forums to find out how to solve it, but I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the PHP plugin installed, you need to create the Web module in your project:
File | New | Module | PHP.
Code completion and full PHP support is only available within a web module.